# SQL - Use result from a Stored Procedure in another Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have something like this:

```
Create Procedure GetStockNumber
@Barcode int

As

Select CodStock from TBL_Stock
Where barcode = @barcode
```

(Let's say the result of the Select is 8 for example)

OK simple :D

BUTTT! I want to use the result (8) of that SP (GetStockNumber) in another SP.
Something like this:

```
Create procedure Blablabla
@Quantity int

As

Update TBL_Stock
Set Quantity = Quantity - @Quantity 
Where CodStock = [THE RESULT OF THE SP (GetStockNumber)]
```

In this case it would be 8 for this example.

So how can I do this?

**

### Solved using the 2º method mentioned by Icarus

**

Comment: "Store Procedure"? Sure you don't mean **stored procedure**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of different options:

1) Return an output parameter from the first stored procedure.

```
Create Procedure GetStockNumber
@Barcode int ,
@CodStock int OUTPUT

As

Select @CodStock = CodStock 
from TBL_Stock
Where barcode = @barcode
```

to use it:

```
DECLARE @CodStock int

EXEC GetStockNumber @BarCode, @CodStock OUTPUT

Update TBL_Stock
Set Quantity = Quantity - @Quantity 
Where CodStock = @CodStock
```

2) Convert the stored procedure to a function that returns a value.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetCodStock(@BarCode INT) RETURNS INT
AS
 BEGIN
   RETURN (SELECT CodStock
             FROM TBL_Stock
            Where barcode = @barcode)
 END
```

To use it:

```
Update TBL_Stock
Set Quantity = Quantity - @Quantity 
Where CodStock = dbo.GetCodStock(@BarCode)
```

Comment: I used The 2º Option and it's working perfectly, exactly what a wanted.

Thank you a lot Icarus :D

Comment: Excellent! Would you mind clicking on the checkbox next to the answer so that future visitors will know that this worked for you without having to read through the comments? Thanks!